# Georeference Canadian postal codes in CartoDB

Tags: carto, canada, postal-code

I'm having issues trying to map by Canadian postal code. I'm prompted with "No rows geocoded in test_cartodb dataset"

[image: Data Set]

[image]

I mapped by "administrative area".

Comment: V7V 2R6 centroid is 49.339151, -123.183857 what are you expecting?

Comment: For CartoDB you will need to use the data source Canadian polygons - http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2011-eng.cfm see this for reference >> https://github.com/CartoDB/data-services/tree/master/geocoder/postal-codes

Comment: @Mapperz that data is the one that the geocoder of the CartoDB SaaS has already, so users of CartoDB.com shouldn't have to upload that data to make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

For Canada, CartoDB (in the SaaS version) is able to geocode Canadian zipcodes only with the first 3 digits, what's called the "Forward Soration Area". So you should be able to map "V7V" and "V6E".

[image: result]